# How do I fade in and out a .WAV file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fadein, wav

I have created a function that takes a .wav file ans plays it . how can i  fade in and out that .wav file when it is played

```
    Dim wav1 As List(Of Byte) = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("hello.wav").ToList
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(wav1.ToArray)
        Using snd As New System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms)
            snd.Play()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the documentation for the sound player class there doesn't look to be any way of changing the volume.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer_properties.aspx

Can you use the mediaplayer class instead and access the volume property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx